# How do I make a report state for scene straits?

Tags: actions-on-google

I saw in GG docs for scene traits. But they don't have states of scenes. Should I make a report state of the scene traits for GG? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If a trait has no states to report, then you wouldn't perform a report state for it. You can set the field `willReportState: false` for that device.